# Not able to pass array name into table view in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, plist

I am relatively new to swift code. Not able to pass the text of array in plist onto table view...

Right now I am getting an empty table view in simulator

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "xml", ofType: "plist")
    if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!), let arrays = dict.object(forKey: "Complete") as? [String: Any] {
        self.ansTopics = arrays
        self.chapters = self.ansTopics.keys.sorted()
    }

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chapters.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainPage", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = chapters[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Here is the plist file

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Complete</key>
<dict>  
<key>Autonomic Nervous System</key>
<array>
    <string>Cholinergic</string>
    <string>Anticholinergic</string>
</array>
<key>Peripheral Nervous System</key>
<array>
    <string>Central relaxants </string>
    <string>Peripheral relaxants </string>
</array>
</dict>
<key>Chap</key>
<array>
<string>Autonomic Nervous System</string>
<string>Peripheral Nervous System</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What's the `self.chapters` output?

Comment: Try once reloading tableview after `self.chapters = self.ansTopics.keys.sorted()` line `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @NiravD Empty simulator

Comment: @Mr.Bista empty output

Comment: `if let dict = NSDictionary(content` condition is satisfied?

Comment: make sure that your path is correct!!

Comment: @Mr.BistaYa i think so as no error reported ... Anything to add on there?

Comment: @Lion I think they are !!! my file name in project is xml

Comment: @NiravD      
this line makes the chapters name appear in alphabetical order ...  self.chapters = self.ansTopics.keys.sorted() anything can be done to avoid it and place it in order ?

Comment: @Nish Dictionary doesn't have any order, so it is not possible to display data in the order that is available in plist file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it may help you

```
let arrays = dict.object(forKey: "Complete") as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
```

Instead of

```
let arrays = dict.object(forKey: "Complete") as? [String: Any]
```

Thanks

Comment: Error: generic parameter "key" couldn't be inferred in cast to "Dictionary<__>"

Comment: as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

Comment: Now self.ansTopics = arrays line throws a bad execution error

Comment: because ansTopic is array and you get dictionary from my code, so change its type to dictionary from array

Comment: this line makes the chapters name appear in alphabetical order ... self.chapters = self.ansTopics.keys.sorted() anything can be done to avoid it and place it in my order of preference ?